# How do I intercept Ctrl-G in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a elisp script for Emacs that I want to do some clean up in if a user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.  I use 'read-event' to catch all events, but this does not catch the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.  When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> is hit, it just stops execution.

In XEmacs, when you call next-command-event it will give you all events including when a user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.  There must be some equivalent in Emacs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `with-local-quit` to determine if `C-g` was pressed:

*Edited solution to swallow quit as suggested by [efunneko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98862/efunneko).*

```
(defun my-c-g-test ()
  "test catching control-g"
  (interactive)
  (let ((inhibit-quit t))
    (unless (with-local-quit
              (y-or-n-p "arg you gonna type C-g?")
              t)
      (progn
        (message "you hit C-g")
        (setq quit-flag nil)))))
```

*Note:* with-local-quit returns the value of the last expression, or `nil` if `C-g` is pressed, so be sure to return something non-nil when no `C-g` is pressed.  I found the elisp documentation on [quitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html) useful.  A related area is [nonlocal exits](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Nonlocal-Exits.html), and specifically [`unwind-protect`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cleanups.html), which applies to more than just quit.

Comment: This solves part of the problem, but it does not swallow the control-g - just lets you know that it happened.  If you want to prevent the control-g from escaping the block, use the 'inhibit-quit' and 'quit-flag' variables.

Comment: This is hideous and brittle.  I'm pretty sure whatever the OP wants can be solved more simply and robustly with either `condition-case` or `unwind-protect`.

Answer (score 9):

`condition-case` and `unwind-protect` are helpful here.  `condition-case` lets you "catch" "exceptions", of which quit is one:

```
(condition-case
    (while t) ; never terminates
  (quit (message "C-g was pressed")))
```

You can also catch other errors, like "error".

`unwind-protect` is like finally; it will execute "body forms" and then "unwind forms".  However, the "unwind forms" are executed regardless of whether the "body forms" ran successfully:

```
(unwind-protect
    (while t)
  (message "Done with infinite loop"))
```

You want `unwind-protect` in your case.

Comment: `condition-case` requires a "var" argument before the body (at least in Emacs 24). I didn't edit your answer because I'm not sure what value you meant to pass there. (Thanks for the answer btw!)